# Cumulatin new column? Window functions in python pandas?

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I am relatively new to python and SQL, seeking for a little help.
I have a dataset where each subject got scores for tasks, it looks like this(sorry dont know how to code df in here):

```
id     task     score
1      1        1
1      2        0
2      1        2
2      2        1
3      1        2
3      2        NaN
```

and I want to make a new column which will have sums of the score of each subject on each row, like this:

```
id     task     score  sum_score
1      1        1      1
1      2        0      1
2      1        2      3
2      2        1      3
3      1        2      2
3      2        NaN    2
```

Thank you for your help, would really appreciate any help, written or redirecting me
I suppose this should work like OVER function in SQL

Comment: `df.groupby('id')['score'].transform('sum')`?

Comment: Are you looking for a panda solution, or a sql solution?

Comment: Pandas solution, but if nothing will help I will use SQL

Comment: did you try the solution from @QuangHoang ?, looks like that is what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pandas it will be written like this :

```py
data = { "id" :  [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],  "task" : [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2],  "score" : [1, 0, 2, 1, 2, np.nan]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df["sum_score"] = df.groupby("id")["score"].transform(np.sum)
```

Results :

```py
    id  task    score   sum_score
0   1   1        1.0      1.0
1   1   2        0.0      1.0
2   2   1        2.0      3.0
3   2   2        1.0      3.0
4   3   1        2.0      2.0
5   3   2        2.0
```